# How to get the variable values of __malloc_printerr__ without debug-info?

Tags: gcc, arguments, disassembly, stdstring, coredump

I have a C++ program which is compiled using gcc4.4.5 and runs on redhat 6.1. The program is compiled with -m64 and the CPU is Intel-64. It always aborts after several days(randomly). Since I can't find the debug-info files for redhat6.1, I have to disassemble the function **malloc_pinterr** to try to figure out the detailed error message. I just could't find out the error message as a newbie to assembly language. I'll be much appreciated if anyone can help on this.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000003caa632a45 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003caa634225 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000003caa66fdfb in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x0000003caa675716 in malloc_printerr () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000003cb729d565 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::assign(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
#5  0x00007f7d73af98de in CSmartIPAddr::convert_ip_2_hex (s_ip="183.95.135.157") at src/common.cpp:627
#6  0x0000000000466f5f in CMDBPacketParser::inner_fill_radius_data (this=0x7f7876bfcbef, unis_set=...) at src/ms_packet.cpp:743
#7  0x0000000000467588 in CMDBPacketParser::inner_parse_radius (this=0x7f7876bfcbef, 
    buf=0x7f7876bf9530 "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><DialUpInfo><Acct-Status-Type>KeepAlive</Acct-Status-Type><User-Name>02703124704</User-Name><Framed-IP-Address>100.87.62.15</Framed-IP-Address><ai-Call-From-Id>6e"..., buflen=684, pktinfo=...) at src/ms_packet.cpp:805
#8  0x0000000000467d9a in CMDBPacketParser::obdparseRaw2App (this=0x7f7876bfcbef, 
    buf=0x7f7876bf9530 "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><DialUpInfo><Acct-Status-Type>KeepAlive</Acct-Status-Type><User-Name>02703124704</User-Name><Framed-IP-Address>100.87.62.15</Framed-IP-Address><ai-Call-From-Id>6e"..., buflen=684, pktinfo=...) at src/ms_packet.cpp:960
#9  0x0000000000457209 in CMDBPeerThread::runCallback (this=0x7f7d6802c700) at src/ms_thread.cpp:3423
#10 0x00007f7d73afb789 in _runThdProc (thd=0x7f7d6802c700) at src/thread.cpp:66
#11 0x0000003cab2077e1 in start_thread (arg=0x7f7876bfd700) at pthread_create.c:301
#12 0x0000003caa6e68ed in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) set disassembly-flavor intel
(gdb) f 3
#3  0x0000003caa675716 in malloc_printerr () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) disas /m
Dump of assembler code for function malloc_printerr:
   0x0000003caa675660 <+0>:     mov    QWORD PTR [rsp-0x10],rbp
   0x0000003caa675665 <+5>:     mov    ebp,edi
   0x0000003caa675667 <+7>:     mov    QWORD PTR [rsp-0x18],rbx
   0x0000003caa67566c <+12>:    mov    eax,ebp
   0x0000003caa67566e <+14>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rsp-0x8],r12
   0x0000003caa675673 <+19>:    sub    rsp,0x38
   0x0000003caa675677 <+23>:    and    eax,0x5
   0x0000003caa67567a <+26>:    mov    rbx,rsi
   0x0000003caa67567d <+29>:    mov    rdi,rdx
   0x0000003caa675680 <+32>:    cmp    eax,0x5
   0x0000003caa675683 <+35>:    je     0x3caa675720 <malloc_printerr+192>
   0x0000003caa675689 <+41>:    test   bpl,0x1
   0x0000003caa67568d <+45>:    jne    0x3caa6756b0 <malloc_printerr+80>
   0x0000003caa67568f <+47>:    and    ebp,0x2
   0x0000003caa675692 <+50>:    jne    0x3caa67573b <malloc_printerr+219>
   0x0000003caa675698 <+56>:    mov    rbx,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x20]
   0x0000003caa67569d <+61>:    mov    rbp,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x28]
   0x0000003caa6756a2 <+66>:    mov    r12,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x30]
   0x0000003caa6756a7 <+71>:    add    rsp,0x38
   0x0000003caa6756ab <+75>:    ret    
   0x0000003caa6756ac <+76>:    nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
   0x0000003caa6756b0 <+80>:    lea    rsi,[rsp+0x10]
   0x0000003caa6756b5 <+85>:    xor    ecx,ecx
   0x0000003caa6756b7 <+87>:    mov    edx,0x10
   0x0000003caa6756bc <+92>:    mov    BYTE PTR [rsp+0x10],0x0
   0x0000003caa6756c1 <+97>:    mov    r12,rsp
   0x0000003caa6756c4 <+100>:   call   0x3caa643d90 <_itoa_word>
   0x0000003caa6756c9 <+105>:   cmp    rax,rsp
   0x0000003caa6756cc <+108>:   mov    r8,rax
   0x0000003caa6756cf <+111>:   jbe    0x3caa6756e8 <malloc_printerr+136>
   0x0000003caa6756d1 <+113>:   nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
   0x0000003caa6756d8 <+120>:   sub    r8,0x1
   0x0000003caa6756dc <+124>:   cmp    r8,r12
   0x0000003caa6756df <+127>:   mov    BYTE PTR [r8],0x30
   0x0000003caa6756e3 <+131>:   ja     0x3caa6756d8 <malloc_printerr+120>
   0x0000003caa6756e5 <+133>:   mov    r8,rsp
   0x0000003caa6756e8 <+136>:   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rip+0x31ab19]        # 0x3caa990208 <__libc_argv>
   0x0000003caa6756ef <+143>:   mov    edi,ebp
   0x0000003caa6756f1 <+145>:   lea    rsi,[rip+0xe0460]        # 0x3caa755b58
   0x0000003caa6756f8 <+152>:   mov    rcx,rbx
   0x0000003caa6756fb <+155>:   mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rax]
   0x0000003caa6756fe <+158>:   lea    rax,[rip+0xde433]        # 0x3caa753b38
   0x0000003caa675705 <+165>:   test   rdx,rdx
   0x0000003caa675708 <+168>:   cmove  rdx,rax
   0x0000003caa67570c <+172>:   and    edi,0x2
   0x0000003caa67570f <+175>:   xor    eax,eax
   0x0000003caa675711 <+177>:   call   0x3caa66fab0 <__libc_message>
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
=> 0x0000003caa675716 <+182>:   jmp    0x3caa675698 <malloc_printerr+56>
   0x0000003caa675718 <+184>:   nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
   0x0000003caa675720 <+192>:   mov    edi,ebp
   0x0000003caa675722 <+194>:   mov    rdx,rsi
   0x0000003caa675725 <+197>:   lea    rsi,[rip+0xdf520]        # 0x3caa754c4c
   0x0000003caa67572c <+204>:   and    edi,0x2
   0x0000003caa67572f <+207>:   xor    eax,eax
   0x0000003caa675731 <+209>:   call   0x3caa66fab0 <__libc_message>
   0x0000003caa675736 <+214>:   jmp    0x3caa675698 <malloc_printerr+56>
   0x0000003caa67573b <+219>:   call   0x3caa6340b0 <abort>
End of assembler dump.
```

The source code of malloc_printerr is as below:

```
static void
malloc_printerr(int action, const char *str, void *ptr)
{
  if ((action & 5) == 5)
    __libc_message (action & 2, "%s\n", str);
  else if (action & 1)
    {
      char buf[2 * sizeof (uintptr_t) + 1];

      buf[sizeof (buf) - 1] = '\0'; 
      char *cp = _itoa_word ((uintptr_t) ptr, &buf[sizeof (buf) - 1], 16, 0); 
      while (cp > buf)
        *--cp = '0';

      __libc_message (action & 2,
                      "*** glibc detected *** %s: %s: 0x%s ***\n", 
                      __libc_argv[0] ?: "<unknown>", str, cp);
    }
  else if (action & 2)
    abort ();
}
```

Basically I want to get the value of str and cp.

Although sometimes it cores when invoking basic_string::assign(), sometimes it cores when invoking  basic_string::~basic_string(), I think it always cores when freeing the string:

```
(gdb) f 4
#4  0x0000003cb729d565 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::assign(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13


(gdb) disas /m
Dump of assembler code for function _ZNSs6assignERKSs:
   0x0000003cb729d4e0 <+0>:     push   rbx
   0x0000003cb729d4e1 <+1>:     mov    rbx,rdi
   0x0000003cb729d4e4 <+4>:     sub    rsp,0x20
   0x0000003cb729d4e8 <+8>:     mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rdi]
   0x0000003cb729d4eb <+11>:    mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsi]
   0x0000003cb729d4ee <+14>:    cmp    rdx,rax
   0x0000003cb729d4f1 <+17>:    je     0x3cb729d51a <_ZNSs6assignERKSs+58>
   0x0000003cb729d4f3 <+19>:    mov    esi,DWORD PTR [rax-0x8]
   0x0000003cb729d4f6 <+22>:    lea    rdi,[rax-0x18]
   0x0000003cb729d4fa <+26>:    test   esi,esi
   0x0000003cb729d4fc <+28>:    js     0x3cb729d528 <_ZNSs6assignERKSs+72>
   0x0000003cb729d4fe <+30>:    mov    rcx,QWORD PTR [rip+0x251483]        # 0x3cb74ee988
   0x0000003cb729d505 <+37>:    cmp    rdi,rcx
   0x0000003cb729d508 <+40>:    jne    0x3cb729d56c <_ZNSs6assignERKSs+140>
   0x0000003cb729d50a <+42>:    lea    rax,[rdi+0x18]
   0x0000003cb729d50e <+46>:    lea    rdi,[rdx-0x18]
   0x0000003cb729d512 <+50>:    cmp    rdi,rcx
   0x0000003cb729d515 <+53>:    jne    0x3cb729d540 <_ZNSs6assignERKSs+96>
   0x0000003cb729d517 <+55>:    mov    QWORD PTR [rbx],rax
   0x0000003cb729d51a <+58>:    mov    rax,rbx
   0x0000003cb729d51d <+61>:    add    rsp,0x20
   0x0000003cb729d521 <+65>:    pop    rbx
   0x0000003cb729d522 <+66>:    ret    
   0x0000003cb729d523 <+67>:    nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
   0x0000003cb729d528 <+72>:    lea    rsi,[rsp+0x1f]
   0x0000003cb729d52d <+77>:    xor    edx,edx
   0x0000003cb729d52f <+79>:    call   0x3cb7255138 <_ZNSs4_Rep8_M_cloneERKSaIcEm@plt>
   0x0000003cb729d534 <+84>:    mov    rcx,QWORD PTR [rip+0x25144d]        # 0x3cb74ee988
   0x0000003cb729d53b <+91>:    mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbx]
   0x0000003cb729d53e <+94>:    jmp    0x3cb729d50e <_ZNSs6assignERKSs+46>
   0x0000003cb729d540 <+96>:    cmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x251808],0x0        # 0x3cb74eed50
   0x0000003cb729d548 <+104>:   je     0x3cb729d588 <_ZNSs6assignERKSs+168>
   0x0000003cb729d54a <+106>:   or     edx,0xffffffffffffffff
   0x0000003cb729d54d <+109>:   lock xadd DWORD PTR [rdi+0x10],edx
   0x0000003cb729d552 <+114>:   test   edx,edx
   0x0000003cb729d554 <+116>:   jg     0x3cb729d517 <_ZNSs6assignERKSs+55>
   0x0000003cb729d556 <+118>:   lea    rsi,[rsp+0x1f]
   0x0000003cb729d55b <+123>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8],rax
   0x0000003cb729d560 <+128>:   call   0x3cb7253eb8 <_ZNSs4_Rep10_M_destroyERKSaIcE@plt>
=> 0x0000003cb729d565 <+133>:   mov    rax,QWORD PTR [rsp+0x8]
   0x0000003cb729d56a <+138>:   jmp    0x3cb729d517 <_ZNSs6assignERKSs+55>
   0x0000003cb729d56c <+140>:   cmp    QWORD PTR [rip+0x2517dc],0x0        # 0x3cb74eed50
   0x0000003cb729d574 <+148>:   je     0x3cb729d593 <_ZNSs6assignERKSs+179>
   0x0000003cb729d576 <+150>:   lock add DWORD PTR [rdi+0x10],0x1
   0x0000003cb729d57b <+155>:   mov    rdx,QWORD PTR [rbx]
   0x0000003cb729d57e <+158>:   jmp    0x3cb729d50a <_ZNSs6assignERKSs+42>
   0x0000003cb729d580 <+160>:   mov    rdi,rax
   0x0000003cb729d583 <+163>:   call   0x3cb72560a8 <_Unwind_Resume@plt>
   0x0000003cb729d588 <+168>:   mov    edx,DWORD PTR [rdi+0x10]
   0x0000003cb729d58b <+171>:   lea    ecx,[rdx-0x1]
   0x0000003cb729d58e <+174>:   mov    DWORD PTR [rdi+0x10],ecx
   0x0000003cb729d591 <+177>:   jmp    0x3cb729d552 <_ZNSs6assignERKSs+114>
   0x0000003cb729d593 <+179>:   add    esi,0x1
   0x0000003cb729d596 <+182>:   mov    DWORD PTR [rax-0x8],esi
   0x0000003cb729d599 <+185>:   jmp    0x3cb729d50a <_ZNSs6assignERKSs+42>
End of assembler dump
```

It's the string hex_ip which causes the core.It's just a local string variable:

```
(gdb) f 5
#5  0x00007f7d73af98de in CSmartIPAddr::convert_ip_2_hex (s_ip="183.95.135.157") at src/common.cpp:627
627     src/common.cpp: No such file or directory.
        in src/common.cpp
(gdb) info args
s_ip = "183.95.135.157"
(gdb) info locals
len = 32
pos = 18446744073709551615
real_ip = "\267_\207\235"
hex_ip = Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/../share/gdb/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 558, in to_string
    return self.val['_M_dataplus']['_M_p'].lazy_string (length = len)
OverflowError: signed integer is greater than maximum

(gdb) p hex_ip._M_dataplus._M_p
$1 = 0x7f76cc000d18 "E"
```

Below is the source snippet,and line 627 is hex_ip = hex_ip.substr(0, (len/8) * 2);

```
string CSmartIPAddr::convert_ip_2_hex(string s_ip)
{   
    if(s_ip.empty())
        return "";

    int     len = 0;
    string::size_type pos;
    string  real_ip = s_ip;
    string  hex_ip = "";
    
    pos = s_ip.find("/");
    if(string::npos != pos) {
        real_ip = s_ip.substr(0, pos);
        len = atoi(s_ip.substr(pos + 1).c_str());

        if(0 >= len)
            return hex_ip;
    }

    real_ip = convert_ip_addr(real_ip);
    if(real_ip.empty())
        return "";
    
    if(0 == len)
        len = real_ip.length() * 8;
    
    hex_ip = cmnConvertBinary2Hex((char*)real_ip.data(), real_ip.length());

    if(0 == len%8)
        hex_ip = hex_ip.substr(0, (len/8) * 2);
    else if(0 < len%8 && 4 >= len%8)
        hex_ip = hex_ip.substr(0, (len/8)*2 + 1);
    else
        hex_ip = hex_ip.substr(0, (len/8 + 1) * 2);

    return hex_ip;
}

string cmnConvertBinary2Hex(char *buf, int buflen) {
  string hex = "";
  int binlen = 2 * buflen + 1;

  if(!buf || (buflen < 0)) {
    return hex;
  }

  char *sbuf = NULL;
  sbuf = (char *) new char[binlen];
  if(!sbuf) {
    //memory not enough
    return hex;
  }

  memset(sbuf, 0, binlen);
  for(int i = 0; i < buflen; i++) {
    my_uint8_t ch = (my_uint8_t)buf[i];
    sprintf(sbuf+2*i, "%2.2x", ch);
  }

  hex = string(sbuf);

  //delete the temp buffer
  delete []sbuf;

  return hex;
}

string CSmartIPAddr::convert_ip_addr(string s_ip)
{
    if(s_ip.empty()) {
        return string("");
    }

    //try ipv4 address
    struct in_addr my_addr_ipv4;

    memset(&my_addr_ipv4, 0, sizeof(my_addr_ipv4));
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, s_ip.c_str(), (void *)((char *)&my_addr_ipv4.s_addr)) > 0) {
        // ok, it's ipv4 address
        return string((char *)&my_addr_ipv4.s_addr, sizeof(my_addr_ipv4.s_addr));
    }

    // try ipv6 address
    struct in6_addr my_addr_ipv6;
    
    memset(&my_addr_ipv6, 0, sizeof(my_addr_ipv6));
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET6, s_ip.c_str(), (void *)my_addr_ipv6.s6_addr) > 0) {
        // ok, it's ipv6 address
        return string((char *)&my_addr_ipv6.s6_addr, sizeof(my_addr_ipv6.s6_addr));;
    }

    return string("");
}
```

Comment: Can you show function `cmnConvertBinary2Hex`?

Comment: I meant you should add the function to the question, not as comment. Now if you also add `convert_ip_addr` we would have a full picture of what this code does.

Comment: @ssbssa Thanks for your warmly reminding. I have add the two functions to the question.

Answer (score 0):

After one-month journey on assembly language, I finally figure out how to get the value of str and cp.

For gcc and x86-64, when a function is called, the arguments from the first to the sixth are passed into registers rdi,rsi,rdx,rcx,r8,r9.

After studying the disas of malloc_pinterr, I found that str is stored in rbx. So get it by entering below command:

```
(gdb) x/1bs $rbx
0x3caa753c88:    "invalid fastbin entry (free)"
```

cp is stored in stack top,so get it by entering below command:

```
(gdb) x/bs $rsp
0x7f3b5bfea4d0:  "00007f3ff80009b0"
```

Since the core file for the question has been deleted, this is from another core file, so the address may seem inconsistent. However, I have checked all the existing core files and the error message is always "invalid fastbin entry (free)".